What is the difference between mergeDescendants = true and clearAndSetSemantics?
I am writing some accessibility for an Android application using JetPack Compose and Kotlin.
I have a button component that is being used as a switch button, it can be selected or unselected.
In terms of UI, when it’s selected it’s white with a close icon to the right, but when it is not, it is reverted to its original color blue without the icon.
I wanna announce when it is selected and when it is not
But actually, I created the button using a text and a close icon. The whole thing is being wrapped up in a row, and I apply the semantics to the row.
I wanna apply the semantics of the row for the whole button, how can I ignore the descendants component, meaning the text and the icon? I don’t want the text and the icon to be called out by accessibility.
On my research, I see that we can use Modifier.clearAndSetSemantics or Modifier.semantics(mergeDescendants = true), which one is the correct one to use? What is the nuance between the two?

You can read the following blog about semantics and clearAndSetSemantics. Hope it helps
https://dladukedev.com/articles/002_semanics_vs_clearandsetsemantics/
